# How to apply multiple filters on Laravel 4 route group?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Is it possible to add multiple filters on a group route in Laravel 4?

I have 2 authentification methods for an API centric application.
One with standard authentification (filter "auth" for website), one with token (filter "auth.token" for mobile app).

```
<?php
    Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/'), function() {
        #Custom routes here
    });
?>
```

Ideally I'd like that **if one of the two filters pass**, group is accessible.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can:

```
Route::group(['before' => 'auth|csrf'], function()
{
     //
});
```

However if you want to make it accesible if **either** of the filters passes, you'd have to write a little bit more (in filters.php):

```
function csrfFilter()
{
    if (Session::token() != Input::get('_token'))
    {
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
}
function authFilter()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::guest('login');
}

Route::filter('csrf-or-auth', function () 
{
    $value = call_user_func('csrfFilter');
    if ($value) return $value;
    else return call_user_func('authFilter');
});
```

In routes.php

```
Route::group(['before' => 'csrf-or-auth'], function()
{
     //
});
```

Remember you have to return nothing when the filter passes.
I hope this helps you!

Comment: There is a syntax error. The code that should be placed in `routes.php` file must be `Route::group(array('before' => 'csrf-or-auth'), function()
    {
         
    });`

Comment: Thanks @Amr. It's fixed now

Comment: You still need to remove one of the last 2 parentheses (those exist before the semicolon). And also apply the same changes on the first snippet of code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with laravel

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'api/', 'before' => 'filter1|filter2'), function()
{
    Route::get('api1', function()
    {
        // Has Filter1 and filter2
    });

    Route::get('api2', function()
    {
        // Has filter1 and filter2
    });
});
```

check the [documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#route-filters) for more details

Comment: The op asked for OR you have explained how to do AND. The | in the before property means AND, its actually just an array seperator.