# How can I make multiple Laravel filters that are 'OR' related?

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel's filters, we can provide a filter `AND` relation like so:

```php
Route::get('user', array('before' => 'auth|old', function()
{
    return 'You are authenticated and over 200 years old!';
}));
```

*(Above example taken from the [Laravel documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-filters))*

Now the above applies both filters `auth` and filter `old` onto the route. If any of them fails, the route is not accessed.

Now I want to apply an `OR` relation, i.e. if **either** `auth` **or** `old` is validated to be true, the filter passes. Is this possible with an easy syntax, or are we required to drudge with `if`-`else-if` statement sets?

In particular, I want to apply this for more than two filters, as `auth\old\tall\famous\martian`, assuming `\` is used for the `OR` relation (like `|` is used for the `AND` relation), and this would check if any among `auth` or `old` or `tall` etc. are validated, and that would validate the combined set of filters.

Comment: This might help you [How to apply multiple filters on Laravel 4 route group?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224096/how-to-apply-multiple-filters-on-laravel-4-route-group)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23224096/how-to-apply-multiple-filters-on-laravel-4-route-group

Comment: It's not possible out of the box you. You have to write your own filter that then validates if at least one is true. What's your real use case? (I highly doubt it's `auth\old\tall\famous\martian`)

Comment: Ah, okay. My real use case is for filtering through a bunch of permissions. As in if the person is the author of the post, or the moderator of the group, or the admin of the group, then offer edit permissions.

Comment: Anyway, thanks all. I suppose it basically confirms that manual `if-else` drudgery is necessary.